# Stop Firefox from putting the I-Beam on non-editable texts

Tags: firefox

Recently I decided to switch to Firefox and found a really annoying problem. The I-Beam appears next to non-editable texts if I click next to them. This breaks the <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys.

[Here's a sample](https://i.imgur.com/g7SsxKs.gifv)

How can I prevent this?

Comment: And next time, **do not blindly click OK in popups**. Firefox actually told you what was going to happen when F7 was accidentally pressed.

Comment: @dotancohen Did it? Do all versions of Firefox issue a dialog box? I use caret browsing from time to time on all the machines where I use Firefox, so maybe it's just been a long time since I was prompted. But this seems like an unwarranted assumption, especially considering that people often share an account on their Ubuntu system or allow friends, family members, coworkers, or IT professionals to use their browser from time to time, and considering it is very easy to accidentally "click" OK if an unexpected popup comes up while you are typing (because pressing the spacebar usually does it).

Comment: I probably just misclicked Enter.

Comment: @EliahKagan: I'm not familiar with OS-X, but the Linux and Windows Firefoxen do pop up a dialogue, and have since at least the sane-versioning days. I completely agree with the sentiment about the space bar "clicking" the dialogue away being problematic, I've seen that happen enough times in enough applications. However, users blindly clicking OK is a common enough issue that I'm comfortable mentioning it here, if not for the OP then for masses of people who will later read this thread.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Press <kbd>F7</kbd>.

This is called [caret browsing](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.browsewithcaret). It is a Firefox feature that lets you move through and select text with your keyboard. <kbd>F7</kbd> toggles it, so if you ever want to use this feature you can press <kbd>F7</kbd> to turn it on, then again to turn it off.

(It is most likely that you had pressed <kbd>F7</kbd> by accident to turn it on this time.)

---

Another way to turn caret browsing on and off is to go to Preferences > Advanced and check/uncheck the box labeled *Always use the cursor keys to navigate within pages* (under Accessibility).

[image: Screenshot of Preferences, Advanced, Accessibility, Always use the cursor keys to navigate within pages]

But <kbd>F7</kbd> is easier.